# Why does a jQuery disabled element look touchable in jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to disable/enable a html select element programatically. My project is using jQuery mobile 1.4.5 and jQuery 2.1.4.

To disable the element in jQuery I do:

```
 $('#filter_refn').prop('disabled', true);
```

Results after rendering in:

```
<select name="ref_id" id="filter_refn" data-mini="true" disabled="">
    <option value="" selected="">Referenznummer auswählen</option>
</select>
```

This "somehow works. As the user can not select anything, however the box is still active and not disabled as it would be by doing it directly in html.

I noticed that the disabled property by jQuery does not contain "true"

example in jQuery mobile:

[image]

native html:

[image]

How can I disable the element in a similar way then in HTML?

Comment: How does the title `Why is a jQuery disabled element touchable?` match the `This "somehow works. As the user can not select anything,`? And id the `however the box is still active and not disabled  about the grayed out look you show in the images? Is you question about appearance or about events/interaction?

Comment: You clearly are using a plugin to transform the `<select>` into something else that looks nicer. When the `disabled` attribute is in the markup, the plugin sees it. When you change the property **after** the plugin ran, it does not know it. --- **What you should do now** is edit you post and indicate what plugin it is and the code to initiate it... So one could reproduce the issue and suggest something.

Comment: Updated the question. jQ mobile and it is about apearance, the UI now suggest that the user can click on it, but the element is somehow disabled and does therefore simple not open but looks like it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the functions provided by the jquery mobile API to change the state of their components.

[Selectmenu Widget: disable()](https://api.jquerymobile.com/1.4/selectmenu/#method-disable):

> $( ".selector" ).selectmenu( "disable" );

The styling of those elements is done by `css` rules and those utilize the `[disabled]` selector.

But if you do `$('#filter_refn').prop('disabled', true);` on a none user input element, then only the property `disabled` changes, but not the attribute. For elements like `select`, `button`, `input`, ... the `$('#filter_refn').prop('disabled', true);` will change both property and attribute.

Writing `$('#filter_refn').prop('disabled', true).attr('disabled', true);` would most certainly also change the visual appearance, but you still should use the functionality provided by the API.

Comment: actually, for all practical purposes, I think $('#filter_refn').attr('disabled', true) alone is enough, from my past experiences, I haven't known a single instance when a "disabled" attribute is dynamically set without the "disabled" property changing accordingly. Of course I'd love to know and stand corrected if there's really such a case when an HTML "disabled" attribute is changed dynamically but the "disabled" property somehow remains unchanged.

Comment: @hellopeach if the property is not set explicitly then its value is based on the attribute. If the property is set then changing the attribute won't affect the property (expect for html elements and attributes where property and attributes are bound)  [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9ckuqy1/). And because jQuery mobile uses a none input element for the select widget the `disabled` attribute and property are not synced and as you don't know how exactly jQuery mobiles implements it a `.attr('disabled', true)` might not be sufficient and as of that you should use their API.

Comment: Thank you. That worked and solved my problem. Unfortunate that such questions get downvoted so fast as from my point of view this was a legit question and your help has led to solving the problem.

Comment: @merlin I didn't down-vote, but if I recall correctly the question got the down votes before you did your first update. And to be fair, before that it was not really clear what you where asking, and not what library you used. The down-vote arrow tool-tip says: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`. It can be argued about the research effort, because the docs provide a working solution to disable a widget in the description of the components, but I don't think that the down-votes were about that.

Answer (score -2):

How is your HTML doctype declared? In XHTML the "disabled" attribute must have a value, while in HTML it doesn't need to have a value. Also it may have something to do with your browser, so it'd be more helpful if you can provide more info on the DOCTYPE declaration and the browser you are using to test the page.

For my latest version desktop Chrome browser

```
<select name="ref_id" id="filter_refn" data-mini="true" disabled>
<select name="ref_id" id="filter_refn" data-mini="true" disabled="">
<select name="ref_id" id="filter_refn" data-mini="true" disabled="disabled">
```

all produce the same result when the doctype is html5, which should be the correct case.

However if your browser or doctype require the "disabled" attribute to have a value, you may use the jQuery "attr" function, that somehow

```
$('#filter_refn').prop('disabled', true);
```

produces

```
<select name="ref_id" id="filter_refn" data-mini="true" disabled>
```

while

```
$('#filter_refn').attr('disabled', true);
```

produces

```
<select name="ref_id" id="filter_refn" data-mini="true" disabled="disabled">
```

and see if that does what you want?

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is a boolean anyway... If it is present in the markup, it is considered true, whatever the string passed to it. Try `disabled="bullshit"`... It works.

Comment: my point is, in XHMTL it is required to have a value, while in HTML it doesn't, and certain browsers can have strange behaviors due to the result of some strange mix of the browser engine version, doctype declaration, and whether you set the value of the disabled attribute. Since the poster said "touchable", I'd guess he's testing with a mobile browser, which complicates the matter even more as some Android phones' built-in browsers are stuck with some quirky version of webkit engine which cannot be upgraded and have some strange issues like this.

Comment: That is not the point anyway... OP is using jQuery... The attribute is tied to the element's property... Using jQuery `.prop()`, the attribute is not changed, only the element's property is.

Comment: Additionnally, there definitely is a plugin instanciated on the `<select>`... And that is OP problem.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette, please read more carefully before commenting next time, the point is, jQuery.prop() and jQuery.attr() produce different results for the browser, prop() produces <disabled> while attr produces <disabled="disabled"> and I've seen in the past certain quirky mobile browsers produce strange results for this kind of stuff, you can try it out yourself and see, and that IS the point.

Comment: My point is that OP problem **is not** the attributes or the property at all. a plugin is used! What he sees are dynamically created elements to mimic a `<select>`. So changing the disabled property does not affect those new elements CSS. The behavior seems to be correct probably because the original `<select>` is used by the plugin. So the disable actually works, but the CSS is incorrect. **That is why I asked** to know which plugin is used and did not answer too fast. -- Please have a second look at the question. *«This "somehow works. As the user can not select anything...»*

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette, my point is the OP's problem COULD be because of the attributes not set according to XHMTL specs or some quirky browser engine. Yes it MAY be because a plugin is used, but it ALSO may be because of the attribute not set as disabled="disabled" since I have SEEN certain mobile browsers do strange things like that, not rendering the content style correctly due to strange mix of doctype and attribute values. That's why I asked the OP to provide more info on the doctype and browser he's using. I'm not saying you are wrong, my point IS the issue COULD be from other reasons.